# XML XSLT to HTML character escape (not the usual)

Tags: xml, xslt

I have inherited a static site built by java/xalan from xml pages.

The html tags in the head of each html doc are all the same included when the site is built. I would like to add a tag in individual xml pages that into which I can insert a tag for the head of that html page. In this case a canonical link tag to indicate duplicate content.

In my XML content page, I have added this:

```
<insertGoodness>link rel="canonical" href="path" /</insertGoodness>
```

Note the absence of the greater than or less than characters.

In my XSL template, the node grabs the data from the xml page and outputs the link tag.

```
<xsl:variable name="insert_Goodness" select="$content/insertGoodness" />
```

```
<xsl:template match="insertGoodness">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<]]></xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$insert_Goodness/node()" />
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[>]]>
    </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

And in my HTML template, I have inserted this in the head section where it should end up.

```
<insertGoodness />
```

Finally, on the html page, I get the output.

```
<link rel="canonical" href="path" />
```

As you can see, I have escaped the greater & less than charaters in the XSL template. Can I do this (put the entire link tag) in my xml content page though as I may want to insert more than one custon tag in the html head section?

I have tried all the escape tricks I can find (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/003e/index.htm) with no luck. Is there a way?

Comment: Yuck. Since you're using Xalan, why not treat `insertGoodness` as a node-set and use actual `link` elements? You can do this using EXSLTs `node-set()` function. (http://www.exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/index.html)

Comment: Double yuck. NEVER HAND-CONSTRUCT SYNTAX. If you want to programmatically write an element to the stylesheet's output, that's what the `<xsl:element>` directive is for.

Comment: Unless I am missed the point, can't you just enter `<insertGoodness><link rel="canonical" href="path" /></insertGoodness>` in your XML content page, and then do `<xsl:copy-of select="$insert_Goodness/node()" />` to output it?

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I'll check out node-set. In the meantime I found a solution - see below.

Tim C - no, the pointy brackets were being outputted as &lt; & &gt;

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best way, but it works and it's only temporary.

In my xsl template file

```
<xsl:template match="insertGoodness">
    <xsl:variable name="tagContent1" select="$content/insertGoodness/node()" />
    <xsl:value-of select="$tagContent1" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
</xsl:template>
```

And then in the xml page

```
<insertGoodness>
    <![CDATA[<]]>link rel="canonical" href="path" /<![CDATA[>]]>
</insertGoodness>
```